# perl: canot open file within a loop

Tags: perl, io

I am trying to read in a bunch of similar files and process them one by one. Here is the code I have. But somehow the perl script doesn't read in the files correctly. I'm not sure how to fix it. The files are definitely readable and writable by me.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @olap_f = `ls /full_dir_to_file/*txt`;

foreach my $file (@olap_f){
    my %traits_h;

    open(IN,'<',$file) || die "cannot open $file";

    while(<IN>){
        chomp;
        my @array = split /\t/;
        my $trait = $array[4];
        $traits_h{$trait} ++;
    }
    close IN;

}
```

When I run it, the error message (something like below) showed up:

```
cannot open /full_dir_to_file/a.txt
```

Comment: Instead of using `ls`, why not use `glob`? It correctly expands `~` in paths.

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper \@olap_f;` will show you exactly what's going on.

Comment: i didn't know glob and Data::Dumper. thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Relevant question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have newlines at the end of each filename:

```
my @olap_f = `ls ~dir_to_file/*txt`;
chomp @olap_f; # Remove newlines
```

Better yet, use [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) to avoid launching a new process (and having to trim newlines):

```
my @olap_f = glob "~dir_to_file/*txt";
```

Also, use [`$!`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$OS_ERROR) to find out why a file couldn't be opened:

```
open(IN,'<',$file) || die "cannot open $file: $!";
```

This would have told you

```
cannot open /full_dir_to_file/a.txt
: No such file or directory
```

which might have made you recognize the unwanted newline.

Comment: chomp solved the problem!! thanks for the other suggestions as well!

Comment: I'd suggest adding - use a lexically scoped filehandle, as it's generally better style. `open ( my $input, "<", $file ) or die $!;`

Answer (score 1):

I'll add a quick plug for [`IO::All`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::All) here. It's important to know what's going on under the hood but it's convenient sometimes to be able to do:

```
use IO::All;
my @olap_f = io->dir('/full_dir_to_file/')->glob('*txt');
```

In this case it's not shorter than @cjm's use of `glob` but `IO::All` does have a few other convenient methods for working with files as well.